# How to get AJAX RESPONSE text from DIV using PHP DOMDocument?

Tags: php, web-crawler, domdocument

I have to recover some text from a div of a site. The div is structured as follows:

The HTML Markup:

```
<div class="content" id="content">
        Loading.....
</div>
```

Content of DIV changes by AJAX function which is on onload of page I guess. and the content of DIV get changes after 1 or 2 seconds.and the HTML structure becomes:

```
<div class="content" id="content">
    <span class"parent">
        <span class="child">
            <span class="sometext">HERE IS SOME TEXT</span>
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

When I use the following PHP function(crawl_page) to grab the HTML of div with ID content it always return (Loading..) which it should be.

What I need is the updated html code, is there anyway to achieve this ?

```
function crawl_page($url)
{
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTMLFile($url);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    $element = $xpath->query("//*[@id='content']")->item(0);
    echo $element->nodeValue;
}

crawl_page("http://example.com/#1:7");
```

Answer (score 3):

i hope its working. And download include file from the below url

```
http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/

<?php
// example of how to use basic selector to retrieve HTML contents
include('../simple_html_dom.php');

// get DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://example.com/#1:7');

// find all link
foreach($html->find('a') as $e) 
    echo $e->href . '<br>';

// find all image
foreach($html->find('img') as $e)
    echo $e->src . '<br>';

// find all image with full tag
foreach($html->find('img') as $e)
    echo $e->outertext . '<br>';

// find all div tags with id=gbar
foreach($html->find('div#content') as $e)
    echo $e->innertext . '<br>';

// find all span tags with class=gb1
foreach($html->find('span.gb1') as $e)
    echo $e->outertext . '<br>';

// find all td tags with attribite align=center
foreach($html->find('td[align=center]') as $e)
    echo $e->innertext . '<br>';

// extract text from table
echo $html->find('td[align="center"]', 1)->plaintext.'<br><hr>';

// extract text from HTML
echo $html->plaintext;
?>
```

Comment: how can i get html that return by ajax using above code ?